# I get a missing permissions error in firebase even though I allow it to read

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a react firebase project.

the error I am getting is

"FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions."

Here is my code to get the data

```js
  const data = await getDocs(
    query(collectionGroup(db, "posts"), orderBy("upvote", "desc"), limit(5)));
```

Here is my firebase security rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /posts/{docId}{
        allow read;
        allow update: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

I have no idea what is going on I allow read in firebase rules but when I go and get the data it does not work

Comment: Does the Firebase Security Rules posted above complete? If not, please update your question with complete security rules.

Answer (score 1):

You should check if in the Database under the rules if read: true and write: true if not make those true.

So go to DataBase-> Rules
make

1. Read:true
2. Write:true

But for production databases allow only for authenticated users